# postfix with if condition

Tags: c, postfix-operator

I have this condition below:

```
 if (MovementDetected)
 {
   if (MovementCount++ == 0)
   {
     TimeCount = WindowTime; /* e.g this is 10 seconds*/
   }
   if (MovementCount > MovementLimit)
   {
     MovementWasDetectedPreviously = TRUE;
   }
   if (MovementWasDetectedPreviously && TimeCount-- == 0)
   {
    Alarm=TRUE;
   }
 }
if (TimeCount-- == 0)
  {
    Alarm=FALSE;
    MovementCount = 0;
  }
MovementDetected = FALSE;
```

I am wondering if the condition **"if (TimeCount-- == 0)"** will decrement the TimeCount by 1 IF the condition is **NOT TRUE**?

Comment: Sure, how would you evaluate the expression *without* evaluating the expression?

Comment: Technically the `TimeCount` will be decremented whether the condition is true or not. If you want it done conditionally, move it inside the if statement (or inside an `else` statement) and check `TimeCount` rather than `TimeCount--`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does decrement check this

```
int i=5;
if(i--  == 0)
{
}
printf("%d\n",i);
```

`i` is 4 so `i` inside `if()` got decremented .

`i--` is a expression which gets executed like `i = i-1` and so the value of `i` will be decremented.

Note the post-decrement returns the value of operand and decrements it.